# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, reactjs

I just started to use React, and when I was trying to do an Ajax call, I got into some trouble.

Im getting:

> Inline JSX script:29Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of null

And I don't know why I am getting the error.

I've tested and if I take:  `{this.state.post}` away from the render function, the `alert(data)` is responding correctly.

Could anyone please help me?

```
   <script type="text/jsx">

        var SomeComponent = React.createClass({

            render: function(){
                return(
                            <h3>{this.props.header}</h3>
                    );
            }
        });

        React.render( <SomeComponent header="Dette er en tittel :)"/>, document.getElementById('content'));

        var EinarsComponent = React.createClass({

            componentDidMount: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.bring.com/shippingguide/api/postalCode.html",
                data: {clientUrl: "localhost", pnr: "4879"},
                success: function(data){
                    this.setState({post: data});
                    alert(data);
                }.bind(this)    
            });
        },
            render: function(){

                return(         
                        <div>{this.state.post}</div>
                    );
            }
        });

        React.render(<EinarsComponent />, document.getElementById('hei'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state of your component is never set, and defaults to `null`. Add a function `getInitialState` in your component:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    post: null // Or some other default value that you fancy
  };
}
```